# Summarizing data to display intervals?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some data comming from a spreadsheet, like so;

```
1|Value1|Value2|Value3|Value4
2|Value1|Value2|Value3|Value4
3|Value1|Value2|Value3|Value4
4|Value1.1|Value2|Value3|Value4
5|Value1.1|Value2|Value3|Value4
6|Value1.3|Value2|Value3|Value4
etc.
```

I am getting the data via LinqToExcel.

I need to display the data in different intervals, depending on the values.
So in state 1, i only need Value1 column, in state 2, Value2 column etc.

The rows go from 1 - 100.

I need to summarize the data somehow, as it is getting displayed like:

```
Value 1.0  |   Value 1.1    | Value 1.2   | Value 1.3
0-23             24-44          45-70         71-100
```

How could i do this?

Comment: a Value could also be in multiple intervals? `0-10, 15, 20-30`?

Comment: The value actually is a color. The usecase is to show a horisontal bar, with x different colors, and below the number. So red is between 0-25, blue is between 26-50 etc. So the value in my example is always a color value. The number 1,2,3 etc, is always a single value.